# Showing that operator is compact

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

*Definition:* Let $X, Y$ be Banach spaces. Then we call a linear map $T: X \to Y$ a compact operator if $\overline{T(K_1^X(0))}$ is compact in $Y$.

$K_1^X(0)$ denotes the ball with radius $1$ and center $0$ in $X$.

*Proposition:* Every $T \in \mathcal B(X,Y)$ with $\mathrm{dim\ ran} \ T < \infty$ is compact.

*Proposition:* The set $\mathcal K(X,Y)$ of all compact operators in $\mathcal B(X,Y)$ is a closed linear subspace of $\mathcal B(X,Y)$ with respect to the operator norm.

**Task:**

Consider the decreasing sequence $(a_n)_{n \in \mathbb N} \in l^1(\mathbb N)$ and the map $A:l^2(\mathbb N) \to l^2(\mathbb N)$ defined as $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb N}\mapsto (\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}a_{k+n-1}x_k)_{n \in \mathbb N}$

I could show that $\|Ax\|_{l^2(\mathbb N)}^2\leq\|x\|_{l^2(\mathbb N)}^2\|a\|_{l^1(\mathbb N)}^2<\infty$.

So, $A$ is well defined and bounded. Also it is clearly linear.  I want to use the first proposition.

> How can I show that $\mathrm{dim\ ran} \ A < \infty$?
>   I don't really know how/where to start.

Comment: Check what $A$ does to the standard basis vectors with $1$ in the $k$-th position and $0$-s elsewhere. The range is not finite dimensional e.g. for $a_n=\frac1{n^2}$.

Comment: First proposition does not give you the answer. Try to approximate $A$ by operators with finite dimensional range.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Can you give me an example of such operators with finite dimensional range which can be used here?

Comment: I would rather go by definition. The result in [How to show that this set is compact in $ℓ_2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/175251/152568) should be useful to you. You need to prove an estimate $|(Ax)_n|\leq c_n$ with $(c_n)\in\ell_2$ for sequences with $\|x\|_{l^2}\leq1$ using that $(a_n)\in\ell_1$. This will show directly that the image of the unit ball has compact closure. I think such estimate here might be related to the [Young's inequality for discrete convolutions](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/70041/152568).