# $\|f*g\|_q\leq \|g\|_q \|f\|_1$ and $\|f*g\|_\infty\leq \|g\|_q \|f\|_{q^{'}}$, $(1/q+1/q^{'}=1)$?

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis, integration, inequality

Now I'm reading the Young inequality. It says that if $f \in L^p(R)$, $g \in L^q(R)$, $1\leq p,q\leq \infty$, $1/p+1/q\geq 1$. Then how could we have the following inequalities:

$$\|f*g\|_q\leq \|g\|_q \|f\|_1$$

$$\|f*g\|_\infty\leq \|g\|_q \|f\|_{q^{'}},\quad (1/q+1/q^{'}=1)$$

$f*g$ means the [convolution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution)

The two inequalities seems not obvious, the second one is similar with the holder inequality, but actually not.

Could someone give me some hints or helpful links? 
Thanks a lot!

Comment: In fact, there's a stronger inequality:

$\|f\ast g\|_r\le \|f\|_p\cdot\|g\|_q$, where $1+1/r=1/p+1/q$ and $p,q,r\in [1,\infty]$. Unfortunately, I can't remember its name (I was taught it was Holder's inequality, but wiki doesn't agree with this name).

Comment: @TZakrevskiy That's Young inequality for convolution, I believe.

Comment: @julien Indeed it is, thank you! Just found it on wiki.

Comment: @TZakrevskiy yes, but Young inequality for convolution is based on the two inequalities. I have a idea to prove that now, meanwhile I am waiting for other elegant proof.

Comment: @Norbert: the OP doesn't want to use Young's Inequality, since this is going to be used to show Young's Inequality. So, although **they should state that in the question**, that is an added requirement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the first inequality using Jensen instead of Young.

If $\|f\|_1=1$, we can use Jensen's inequality on the measure $\mathrm{d}\mu=f(x-y)\,\mathrm{d}y$ to get
$$
\left|\int f(x-y)g(y)\,\mathrm{d}y\right|^p\le\int |f(x-y)||g(y)|^p\,\mathrm{d}y
$$
Then integrate with respect to $x$ to get
$$
\|f\ast g\|_p^p\le\|f\|_1\|g\|_p^p=\|f\|_1^p\|g\|_p^p
$$
since $\|f\|_1=1$. This equation now scales nicely with $\|f\|_1$, so we can remove the restriction that $\|f\|_1=1$ to get
$$
\|f\ast g\|_p\le\|f\|_1\|g\|_p
$$

---

As mentioned by julien, the second inequality is simply Hölder's inequality.

Answer (score 2):

The second inequality is easy. The first one is tricky, and was already proved by robjohn here as an answer to a different question. I just answer this for the sake of completeness because I couldn't find a proof of the second inequality here.

2) For the second inequality, I assume $1<q<\infty$ as the cases $q=1$ and $q=\infty$ are trivial. First note that
$$
|(f\ast g)(x)|=\Big|\int f(x-y)g(y)dy\Big|\leq \int |f(x-y)||g(y)|dy
$$
then  by Hölder and variable change
$$
\leq \left(\int|f(x-y)|^{q'} \right)^\frac{1}{q'} \left(\int|g(y)|^{q} \right)^\frac{1}{q}=\left(\int|f(y)|^{q'} \right)^\frac{1}{q'} \left(\int|g(y)|^{q} \right)^\frac{1}{q}
$$
whence
$$
\|f\ast g\|_\infty \leq \|f\|_{q'}\|g\|_q.
$$

1) The first inequality is a particular case of [Young's inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Young%27s_inequality)
$$
\|f\ast g\|_s\leq \|f\|_p\|g\|_q\qquad\mbox{when}\quad \frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{q}=1+\frac{1}{s}, \quad 1\leq p,q,s\leq \infty
$$
which is proved by robjohn in [this thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/69921/convolution-of-an-l-p-mathbbt-function-f-with-a-term-of-a-summability). This does not cover the cases when $p,q,$ or $s$ are infinite. But $s=\infty$ is the case above, and your inequality has $p=1$, which yields $s=q$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.The second inequality, in deed, can be showed by holder inequality, which I don't get it at first. And the first inequality, could you show that without using the Young's inequality? Because in my book, we have these two inequalities to prove the Young's inequality. If I use it, that will lead to argue in a circle.

Comment: @user39843 In that case, just mimick robjohn's proof making $p=1$ and $s=q$.

Comment: @julien: there is a simpler method using Hölder for the case that $f\in L^1$.

Comment: @robjohn Right, thanks for the note.  You meant Jensen, I guess, as your answer shows.

Comment: @julien: Jensen indeed. I'm doing too much at once :-)

Comment: @user39843: I assume you are talking about
$$
\begin{align}
\iint |f(x-y)||g(y)|^p\,\mathrm{d}y\,\mathrm{d}x
&=\iint |f(x-y)||g(y)|^p\,\mathrm{d}x\,\mathrm{d}y\\
&=\iint |f(x)||g(y)|^p\,\mathrm{d}x\,\mathrm{d}y\\
&=\int |f(x)|\,\mathrm{d}x\,\int |g(y)|^p\,\mathrm{d}y\\
&=\|f\|_1\|g\|_p^p
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Sorrt that I make a mistake. Now I have known what you said. @robjohn, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I'll give a proof just using Holder's Inequality so that it may easier for you to understand, but as the above comments said the proof for these inequalities is already somewhere else.

Proof for the first: By Holder's Inequality we have
\begin{align*}
\left|\int f(x-y)g(y)dy\right|\le&\int|f(x-y)|^{1/q}|g(y)||f(x-y)|^{1-1/q}dy
\\
\le&\left(\int|f(x-y)||g(y)|^qdy\right)^{1/q}\left(\int|f(x-y)|dy\right)^{1-1/q}
\\
=&\|f\|_1^{1-1/q}\left(\int|f(x-y)||g(y)|^qdy\right)^{1/q},\qquad\forall x.
\end{align*}
Then by Fubini Theorem we have
\begin{align*}
\|f*g\|_q^q\le&\|f\|_1^{q-1}\int\int|f(x-y)||g(y)|^qdydx
\\
=&\|f\|_1^{q-1}\int\left(|g(y)|^q\int|f(x-y)|dx\right)dy
\\
=&\|f\|_1^{q}\|g\|_q^q.
\end{align*}
Taking off $q$ we prove the first one.

The proof for the second one: By Holder's Inequality we have
\begin{align*}
\left|\int f(x-y)g(y)dy\right|\le\left(\int|f(x-y)|^{q'}dy\right)^{1/q'}\left(\int|g(y)|^qdy\right)^{1/q}=\|f\|_{q'}\|g\|_{q},\qquad\forall x.
\end{align*}
By taking the supremum we get the second one.

Comment: Hölder is Jensen using the convex function $x^p$ where $p\ge1$. (+1)

Comment: Yes, but the change of measure is needed.

Comment: In most applications of Jensen, a change of measure is needed:

$$
\begin{align}
\left(\int f g\,\mathrm{d}x\right)^p
&=\|g\|_q^{pq}\left(\int\frac{f}{g^{q-1}} \left(\frac{g}{\|g\|_q}\right)^q\,\mathrm{d}x\right)^p\\
&\le\|g\|_q^{pq}\int\left(\frac{f}{g^{q-1}}\right)^p \left(\frac{g}{\|g\|_q}\right)^q\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\|g\|_q^{pq-q}\int f^pg^{p+q-pq}\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\|g\|_q^p\|f\|_p^p
\end{align}
$$